# How to make an image used by multiple pages load only once

Tags: html, image

On my website I use the same background image for each page, if possible I would only like it to be downloaded once to the user so that it doesn't have to be downloaded again on each click.

How would I do this?

[Link to my website](http://www.trinity-international.com)

Comment: This image should be cached by browser and won't be downloaded on each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**off-topic:** Do not use `background-image` on `html` tag! use it on `body`.

**about your problem:** because you used `sub-domain` and each time it will load your bg from different url. anyway, there is a solution, that use full url to load image for background, for all pages. **like this:**

```
html {
    background: url(http://www.trinity-international.com/tower3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

but i advise to use this:

```
body {
    background: url(http://www.trinity-international.com/tower3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly (Y) thanks! Will change to body too, beginner's error!